# xdebug PHP 7.2 в Ubunu 16.04

Tags: xampp, xdebug

**[РЕШЕНО]**

Проблема в том, чтобы скомпилировать новый xdebug мне нужен phpize новой версии, не знаю где ее найти или как без нее установить xdebug.
Установлен последний XAMPP с PHP 7.2 в файлах нашел phpize-7.2.0 Но не из той директории  и из другой phpize не запускается. Есть ли он в сборке изначально? И как мне можно поставить xdebug? Мучаюсь уже 2 день.

***У кого большой рейтинг, если сможете, добавьте метку phpize, вдруг кто-то будет и этот вопрос решать.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если ранее XAMPP был установлен, удаляем его, вызвав деинсталлятор из директории opt/lampp
2. Далее для очистки остатков

   - sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
   - sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php*
   - sudo apt-get clean
   - sudo apt-get autoclean
   - sudo apt-get autoremove
   - sudo apt-get -f install
3. Обновляем репозиторий

   - sudo apt install python-software-properties
   - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   - sudo apt update
4. Ставим phpize for PHP 7.2

   - sudo apt install php7.2-dev
5. В php.ini (В LAMPP он /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini) заносим в данном порядке, чтобы не было конфликтов. Если opcache.so не нужен закомментируйте, вдруг после пригодиться (а так порядок не испортится)

   - zend_extension=opcache.so
   - zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
6. Перезапускаем Apach и смотрим в phpinfo()
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
7. В /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini/xdebug.ini добавляем (если файла нет - создаем)

   zend_extension=xdebug.so

   xdebug.remote_autostart = on

   xdebug.remote_enable = 1

   xdebug.remote_port = 9000

   xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"

   xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
8. А далее сами настраиваем PHPShtorm или что там у вас)))

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления phpize у меня сработало следующее:

1. `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get`
   dist-upgrade -y
2. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev`
3. После чего успешно выполнилось `pecl install xdebug`